# GoDaddy blocks sending emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, smtp

I have a web app that uses **SMTP** to send emails (just simple contact us form). But when user submits form I see this error:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden 
                         by its access permissions 173.201.193.228:25
```

**Why is this?** Locally emails works well + when I deploy this on **Azure** I don't have this problem. See this error on **GoDaddy** hosting only.

Comment: Can you show the code that's sending the email? What happens when you alter the permissions set for your app on GoDaddy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Go Daddy's Help Center](https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122):

> Your server must send mail using our relay servers. This prevents
>   abuse of our network and helps ensure our customers don't get
>   blacklisted for using the same network as a spammer.

You can use Go Daddy's email relay server (instructions in the [linked documentation](https://www.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122)), or a 3rd Party service over a protocol other than SMTP, for instance Amazon Simple Email Service via the [SES API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html).